# Python 3.5 streaming output to the same log file that I write too

Tags: python-3.x, logging, streaming

I am new to python, and am trying to work out a logging issue.  I am trying to stream stdoout, as well as stderr, to the log file that I also manually write entries to when using log...

Also, I am getting duplicate entries on the console, but only one entry in the actual log file, when I manually log entries.

```
import os 
import datetime
from subprocess import call
import sys
import logging


currDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
today_key = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
log_file = os.path.join(currDir, "logs", 'stream_'+today_key)+".log"
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s — %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d — %(message)s')
pStart = datetime.datetime.now()

def get_stdout_handler():
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stdout_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    return stdout_handler

def get_stderr_handler():
    stderr_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    stderr_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    return stderr_handler

def get_file_handler():
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, 'a')
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    return file_handler

def get_logger(logger_name):
    log = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
    log.addHandler(get_stdout_handler())
    log.addHandler(get_stderr_handler())
    log.addHandler(get_file_handler())
    log.propagate = False
    log.hasHandlers = True

    return log

def restore_db():

    call(["ping", "google.com"])


logger = get_logger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('-----------------------------------')
    logger.info('process start')
    restore_db()
    logger.info('process end')
    logger.info('total processing time (%s)',(datetime.datetime.now() - pStart))
    logger.info('-----------------------------------')
```

The stream from the ping doesn't appear at all in the log file.